# Group feed lacks polls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group, facebook-feed

I'm fetching a group's feed https://graph.facebook.com/my_group/feed, but it completely ommits polls and links posted in group. Is there a way to get polls along with other posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They just announced this is available on their [blog.](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/590/)To get them, issue an HTTP GET request to the USER_ID/questions endpoint with the user_questions or friends_questions permissions.

It is not available yet. See [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=74595)

they also just [announced](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/) that you can create questions now via the API.